# How do I omit webforms submission number (serial) from results?

Tags: webforms

We have webforms that use Webform Entity Print (PDF) Attachment. These PDFs have Submission number show up right after form's headline. How do I hide this number so it doesn't show up in the results?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm new to Drupal and downvoting doesn't make me feel very welcome. Some need to get off their high horse.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :) Just in case you haven't seen it yet, it's worth to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help). There are a ton of good tips in it that will improve your chances of getting high quality answers.

Answer (score 2):

In Submission General Settings area in "Submissions label" enter available token of your choice from "next submission number" area. For example adding [webform_submission:submitted-to]: [current-date:site_short_format] to Submission label will show webform's title and date in the results.
[image]